# How can I filter the data via date on RESTHeart

Tags: restheart

I get the following data from the RestHeart API service. I try to filter the data by

```
filter={'header.timestamp.long':{'$gte': {'$date':'2017-02-14T19:00:00Z'}}}
```

or

```
filter={'header.timestamp.long.$numberLong':{'$gte': {'$date':'2017-02-14T19:00:00Z'}}}
```

but they are not working. 
The response is

```
{
  "_embedded": [],
  "_id": "logs_43990547141907029933",
  "_size": 0,
  "_total_pages": 0,
  "_returned": 0
}
```

My RestHeart is V3.0.

Thank you for your helping.

Data:

```
{
  "_embedded": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58a3ffc5e90174170ed22786"
      },
      "header": {
        "timestamp": {
          "long": {
            "$numberLong": "1487142853743"
          }
        }
      },
      "event": {
        "Measurements": {
          "lifevo．mead．smarthome．TemperatureData": {
            "Temperature": 23.977264
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "58a3ffc2e90174170ed22785"
      },
      "header": {
        "timestamp": {
          "long": {
            "$numberLong": "1487142850744"
          }
        }
      },
      "event": {
        "Measurements": {
          "lifevo．mead．smarthome．TemperatureData": {
            "Temperature": 21.15203
          }
        }
      }
    },
     ......


 ],
  "_id": "logs_43990547141907029933",
  "_returned": 100
}
```

Comment: I also try    
filter={"header.timestamp": {"$gte": {"$date":"2017-02-14T00:00:00Z"}}}, I still can not get any data

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.2.11

Answer (score 0):

Your properties in mongodb are not of type Data, but just long numbers.

Don't use $date in your filter.

Comment: Hi Andrea,
   Thank you for your answer. I misunderstand that long is date in mongodb.